# Translating string in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I've developed a site in english (admin & front end) but the site needs to be in a Dutch. Locale and i18n modules have been installed.

Dutch has been added to the list of languages and set as default in admin/settings/language.

I'm now wondering how I can translate strings like the date output? For ex, when I print out a date from a view, it still outputs the days and months in English.

In admin/settings/language/configure I've selected "path prefix only" but I don't get the language code in the url's and links. How is this achieved?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate month names, days and much more using Translation interface. Navigate to:

**Administer** -> **Site Building** -> **Translate interface** (admin/build/translate) -> **Search** (admin/build/translate/search)

and use the search form to locate the string you wish to translate.

Since you've already added Dutch to your site, you can download entire Dutch translation on http://localize.drupal.org. Site is currently in beta, so you will have to login using your Drupal.org credentials.

Use [this link](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/nl/export?project=drupal) to export Dutch translation of Drupal. Just make sure you choose *All in one file* format so you can easily import it in your site using **Translate interface** -> **Import**

To get the language code in the URLs you will have to enable Multilingual support for each content type you need translated (admin/content/types) by opening edit and selecting desired option under **Workflow settings** -> **Multilingual support**.

After that make sure that you specify Dutch/English language while adding or editing nodes.